# JavaScript: Map return undefined object despite object exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have stranger problem. I have Map() with objects. When I try to get object using map.get() method, I received 'undefined' object.

In attachment is quite clear explanation. Why is X undefined?

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be great if you add a codepen.

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text rather than an image within the question. You can format it as a block of code using the `{}` button in the post editor, which has a shortcut of `Ctrl`+`K`, or by adding 4 spaces in front of each line.

Comment: I added image because I would like show information from debugger, but you are right, it is not best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a mismatch of types.

```
console.log( "14" === 14 ); // false
```

You'll need to convert `id` to a number to match the key correctly:

```
var id = Number($scope.eventId); // id = 14

// ...

var x = mmap.get(id);   // x = ["SIGN_UP", "ENABLED"], ...
```

---

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will match a key by strict equality ([`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_())), which first requires that the value's types are the same.

The keys within the `Map` appear to be numbers:

```
Map { ..., 14 => ["SIGN_UP", "ENABLED"], ... }
```

While the `id` is a string:

```
id = "14"
```

Going by the debugger output highlighted in orange.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Lonowski - everything works!